# How to export 3d model while preserving materials?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, export

I want to export a 3d model to different file formats (.fbx, .obj, .stl, .dae) yet I when I import them again in blender the materials are different. Glass BSDF gets turned into Prncipled BSDF and shading nodes are gone. What can I do?
[image]

Comment: all these other formats only support some shaders like the Principled BSDF so I guess you need to stay basic

Comment: As @moonboots says most of Blender's shaders can only be used in Blender. See [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures).